# OSX Safari (9.1.1) Audio object 'paused' flag constantly true

Tags: safari, html5-video, html5-audio

Using OSX Safari 9.1.1, I get the issue as described in the title: the `paused` property is always true, even when the audio is playing.

I create the audio object like so

```
this.audio = new Audio();
this.audio.autoplay = false;
this.audio.preload = 'metadata';
this.audio.src = 'https://example.com/audio.mp3';
this.audio.load();
```

And I tested it like this:

```
console.debug(`Before play: ${this.audio.paused}`);
this.audio.play();
console.debug(`After play: ${this.audio.paused}`);
```

The `paused` property will always be true. Even when I have called `play()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: always like even if you do call `audio.paused` in the console some time after ? in latests [revs of whatwg](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#dom-media-play) `HTMLMediaElement.play()` returns a Promise, (not in w3c) which makes it an async call, I don't know about latest Safari though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

Comment: Yup, returns `true` even while it's actually playing.

Comment: Oh actually 9.1.1 is not the latest one. I can't repro on 9.1.3 (latest on macos 10.9) and latest one is 10.0. (only available in macos10+) So, try to update your browser :-P

Comment: Hmm okay, as a developer, that doesn't sound very comforting. The fact that the website doesn't work on a default OSX installation.

I can't update Safari either. I am using OSX El Capitan and it doesn't show that any updates are available for Safari.

Comment: Well according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history), 10.0 should be available on El Capitan since September. And as a developer, you can't handle all the bugs that web-browser's devs have dispersed in all the versions of their soft. That's why they do update it. (Only workaround I can think of right now btw would be as ugly as checking for currrenTime change, which would make your check async.)

Comment: Yeah, did an OS update and it works on Safari 10. I guess it is a Safari 9.1.1 bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a Safari 9.1.1 bug.